# How to save specific links/directories on blog using Wget

Tags: wget

(FYI: I'm totally new to Windows command line and Wget.) I'm having issues saving the links I want while archiving a blog. The blog site's archive is separated out by year, so I navigate to the year I want and start from that page. Within that page may be 2-4 pages. I'm able to grab those pages, but I can't figure out how to also save specific directories/links that are on the pages. (So, say that there's a blog post that is too long for the archive to show in full, so it has a "click here to read full post" link. I only want those links, the ones that are within the blog's domain. Also, I don't care about grabbing anything other than the text on the site. So, I don't really need graphics, etc. Here are the arguments I've been trying out:

`wget.exe -r -l1 -P filename --no-parent https://link`

`wget.exe -E -H -k -K -p -r -P filename -np -l1 https://link`

`wget.exe -r -l1 -I /blog -P filename https://link`

When I tried those, they either grabbed too many external links (and not the ones I wanted), or only grabbed the pages within the blog archive's year.

Answer (score 0):

> grabbed too many external links

If you want to limit that you might use [Recursive Accept/Reject Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html) in your case I suggest giving a try to

```
--accept-regex urlregex
--reject-regex urlregex

Specify a regular expression to accept or reject the complete URL.
```

but keep in mind that it needs to match *whole* URL, if e.g. I want grab recursively only links which contain `someblog` anywhere I could express that using

```
--accept-regex ".*someblog.*"
```

`.` in regex means *any character*, `*` in regexs means repeated zero-or-more times